# Are lambda layer and lambda requirements.txt dependencies automatically resolved?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

For a lambda function I have a requirements.txt file, and also a lambda layer. In both the lambda layer and the requirements.txt file for the lambda function I have included psycopg2. Will pip install -r requirements still try install psycopg2 or will it recognize it is in the layer and not need to be installed?

Comment: Where are you running pip install? Lambda does not install any dependencies, in simply unpacks the layers and merges it all into one file system.

Comment: @luk2302 So we are running the pip install in bundling options. This is because we are using private repos with utility functions. So I believe we are getting a dockerized lambda. Using the following cdk code `aws_lambda.Code.from_asset(... command=["bash","-c","pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output"])` and then attaching that asset to the lambda function. Wondering if I should take out the requirement of psycog2 from the private repo and just assume the lambda layer will have it

Comment: Yes, you can ignore it in that case. The code of your lambda and all layers are basically just merged into one.